How to download all audios from the com.android.deskclock application in android using adb?
The issue is that I couldn't find the audio files for this application. Is there any way to do this, for example, using ADB, which I can run from the notebook menu.

By "all audios", did you mean the audio/sound effects from the app, or the sound files like alarms?

The default android app comes with several sounds, I want to download them.
